# How to map an array reference in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust, iterator

I have this array

```
let buffer: &[u8] = &[0; 40000];
```

But when I want to map it like this:

```
*buffer.map( |x| 0xff);
```

I have the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `map` found for type `&[u8]` in the current scope   
     --> src/bin/save_png.rs:12:13
    | 
 12 |     *buffer.map( |x| 0xff); //.map(|x| 0xff);
    |             ^^^
    |
    = note: the method `map` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&mut &[u8] : std::iter::Iterator`
            `&mut [u8] : std::iter::Iterator`
```

I tried several ways to do the elements mutable but I can't get the right syntax. Anyone have experience? I'm trying to work with a png image buffer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The type `&[T]` doesn't have a `map` method. If you look at the error message, it is telling you that a method called `map` exists but it won't work for `&mut &[u8]` or `&mut [u8]` because those types do not implement `Iterator`.  Arrays and other collections usually have a method, or set of methods, for creating an iterator. For a slice or an array, you have the choice of either `iter()` (iterating over references) or `into_iter()` (iterating over moved values and consuming the source collection).

Usually, you'll also want to collect the values into some other collection:

```
let res: Vec<u8> = buffer
    .iter()
    .map(|x| 0xff)
    .collect();
```

Comment: Can you get an array back, instead of converting to `Vec`?

Comment: @Ixx you can't get an array back because `.collect()` doesn't know how long the input is, and arrays are of fixed length in rust. You can see all the things you can collect into by seeing what implements `FromIterator`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#implementors